# export array as Component prop using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, reactjs, export

I am wondering if there is a way to have an array of React elements in one file and then export that for import into another file with props? Something like...

```
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';


exports.menuItems = [
  <MenuItem primaryText='Make glue' onTouchTap={this.props.makeGlue}/>, //<-- I am guessing props cannot be passed like this???
  <MenuItem primaryText='Make more sticky glue'/>
]
```

... and then import menuItems into another file as a child of another component? I would like to keep various arrays of different menuIems in one file and import them into others as needed. Any thoughts or ideas? I untimately prefer to have server arrays of different menuItems exported from a single file if that's possible.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entirely better off just making a component that does what you're saying. Remember that components are just functions so you can pass props along.

```
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

export default ({ makeGlue }) => {
  return [
    <MenuItem primaryText='Make glue' onTouchTap={makeGlue} />,
    <MenuItem primaryText='Make more sticky glue'/>
  ]
}
```

Either way, this function takes some props and returns the components you want in array form.

Comment: Thanks - figured as much based on what I had tried and read. It'll be a bit more verbose to handle redundant dynamic items this way, but it's OK.

Comment: How do you use this? I can't get this to render in the parent.

Comment: @CraigHowell which part in particular? Can you make a new stackoverflow question and add the link here? This is very old question / answer now

Comment: Specifically importing the array of components into another component and using it

Comment: @CraigHowell It's component, you import it and render like any component `import C..  <C />`